# How do I use multiple triggers in an Azure Logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-sync

I'd like to sync fresdesk tickets on create or update - do I have to create 2 seperate logic apps, one for create and one for update, or can I somehow create an "or" trigger in the logic app for either create or update events - then flow that into the same update document db step?

If I look at the code view, can I just add multiple triggers to the json definition?  e.g.

```
"triggers": {
        "When_a_ticket_is_created": {
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "api": {
                        "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-northcentralus.azure-apim.net/apim/freshdesk"
                    },
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['freshdesk']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/trigger/ticketcreated/api/v2/tickets",
                "queries": {
                    "updated_since": "2016-08-19T02:00:00Z"
                }
            },
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 5
            },
            "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        },
        "When_a_ticket_is_updated": {
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "api": {
                        "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-northcentralus.azure-apim.net/apim/freshdesk"
                    },
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['freshdesk']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/trigger/ticketupdated/api/v2/tickets",
                "queries": {
                    "updated_since": "2016-08-19T02:00:00Z"
                }
            },
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 5
            },
            "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        }
```

Comment: there's an if step, that could help, probably

Comment: I see in the docs that triggers supports multiple - but doesn't seem to take an array in the json - not sure what the correct syntax is.